# Cakephp share database configuration for multiple apps

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I have a CakePHP installation with multiple apps that has this structure:

`/cake-1.3.10
/cake-2.3.0
/apps/app 1
/apps/app 2
/...
/apps/app N
/apps/_shared/Cake_v1/Component
/apps/_shared/Cake_v1/Model
/apps/_shared/Cake_v2/Component
/apps/_shared/Cake_v2/Model`

So what happens here is that all the apps grab the v1.3 or v2.3 cores (depending on which version of the framework they use). In addition, I have some Components and Models that all the apps share. Each app loads those from the `_shared` folder depending on its version.

Until here all works great.

Now, I would like to do the same for the database configuration. Each app has its own `/config/database.php` file. How would I go about making it so ALL apps share the same `database.php` file? Actually I would have 2 database.php files, one per version, since they're different (like with Components and Models). But I'm not sure what exactly I need to change to accomplish that.

Comment: Would it be possible to just make symlinks to the appropriate database.php file?

Comment: well, I guess I could do something like that, sounds like a good idea. Although if possible I would prefer to do it more like in a "cakephp" way, but if I can;t figure it out yours sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that there is easy CakePHP way. You have to modify **/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php** . In version 2.3 on line 69 there is

```
include_once APP . 'Config' . DS . 'database.php';
```

I don't see there any code that allows the configuration. It looks hardcoded.

More elegant way is that you make symbolic links as @Kai mentioned. Then you can upgrade CakePHP without having to remember about your little hack.